# How do I select a certain part of a char array to use in a function

Tags: java, arrays, encryption

I am making a school project about encrypting a message. I am trying to implement AES. This all is working fine, except for using the padded message in the main function. The maximum number of bytes this function is able to use is 16. I am trying to use only 16 bytes per circulation of the `for` loop.

```
for(int i=0;i<lenOfPaddedMessage;i += 16){
    AES_Encrypt(paddedMessage + i, expendedKey);
}
```

How do I get to use 16 bytes of the `char[] paddedMessage`?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-byte:A-int-int-

Answer (score 0):

with paddedMessage.getBytes get an array of byte and use 16 bytes of that array.